# Different form view when different account type logs in

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

i am trying to make my login form to load a different form when someone logins as a student, when a student enters, it will go to lobby.cs form but it will only show 1 button, and when a admin enters, it will also go to lobby.cs form but it will show all the buttons. problem: even when the admin logs in, it only shows the what the students should see. Database is already good, types are set as ADMIN for admin accounts and STUDENT for student accounts
code below from lobby.cs

```
try
{
    adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Type = @type", con);
    adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@type", "ADMIN");
    dt = new DataTable(); adp.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
    {
        button2.Visible = true;
        button3.Visible = true;
        button4.Visible = true;
        button5.Visible = true;
        button1.Visible = true;
        button6.Visible = false;
        con.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Type = @type", con);
        adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@type", "STUDENT");
        dt = new DataTable(); adp.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {
            button2.Visible = false;
            button3.Visible = false;
            button4.Visible = false;
            button5.Visible = false;
            button1.Visible = true;
            button6.Visible = true;
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    con.Close();
}

con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE Status = 'IN'", con);

using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (read.Read())
{
    textBox1.Text = (read["Username"].ToString());
}
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Your use of IF is weird - you always call admin, and if dt.Rows[0][0] == "1" you show admin else rerun as student ....  but your query is counting ALL users so if you have 0 or 2+ admin users its going to display student

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
```

Is saying if there exists exactly one Admin, then show the login form for Admin. Otherwise, if 0, or 2 or more admins exist, then show the Student form.

If this is before the login, you'll need some way to determine from the page if it's the admin login or not. Whether this is a querystring parameter, stored cookie, or a separate login page altogether.

If this is supposed to happen after login, and you already know and have verified the user, you could modify your query to something like:

```
adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT 1 FROM Users WHERE Type = @type and username = @username", con);
adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@type", "ADMIN");
adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@username", loggedInUserName);
dt = new DataTable(); adp.Fill(dt);

if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1") {
    // Admin
}
else {
    // Student
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it needs an overhaul to your code because of the following:

1. You have too many database travel. (you can get those data in one shot).
2. Your condition in user type is confusing, you are getting all of the users with "ADMIN" and "STUDENT", you should get it on the query where you are getting the username.

Please refer to the code below:

```
try
{
    var sql = "SELECT Username, Type  FROM Users WHERE Username = @username AND Password = @password AND STATUS = 'IN'"
    var isLogin = false; //check if user successfully logged it
    var userType = ""; //for user type...
    using (var sqlConn = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
    {
        sqlConn.Open();
        var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConn);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", username));
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", password)); //I hope you had this field...
        using (var reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                textBox1.Text = reader["Username"].ToString(); //put it to the text box.
                userType = reader["Type"].ToString(); //put the result type in the variable..
                isLogin = true;
            }
        }
    }

    //check if has user
    if (isLogin)
    {
        //just check the user type variable...
        if (userType == "ADMIN")
        {
            button2.Visible = true;
            button3.Visible = true;
            button4.Visible = true;
            button5.Visible = true;
            button1.Visible = true;
            button6.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            button2.Visible = false;
            button3.Visible = false;
            button4.Visible = false;
            button5.Visible = false;
            button1.Visible = true;
            button6.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("User doen't exist");
    }

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
```